# MySQL insert between ID's

Tags: mysql, insert

If I have a database with the following information, how can I setup my next `INSERT` query so that the ID is filled in? (so that it is 5 in this instance.)

[image]

Basically, once it gets to 24, it will continue inserting in order (ex: 30,31,32)

Comment: Your application logic should **NEVER** rely on the actual primary key value. So basically you should care if it's 5 or 555 value there.

Comment: Auto-incrememnt keys are intended to ensure _uniqueness_, not sequentiality.  If you need to write incrementing numbers in your application code, do so in your fetch loop.

Comment: well I do not want the Filename to be something extreme like /files/uploads/57427689.jpg if that time ever comes and theres about 300,000 empty/deleted rows that it could use instead.

Comment: How is that filename "extreme"?  If you're making the filenames be integers, and that's an integer, then it fits the design.  If you don't like the filenames the perhaps you should change them so they're not tightly coupled to the table's primary key?  The table has the filenames in it so each record already points to its file, so there's no need to make them the primary key.

Comment: Even then you can just bump the size of the primary key up.  I'm pretty sure you will run into other issues before having a billion rows in a table.

Comment: @sakkaku: Indeed, having a billion files in one folder is probably going to strain the filesystem in interesting ways.

Answer (score 2):

You don't.  Not with an auto-incrementing integer anyway.

You could change the column to not be an auto-incrementing integer, but then you'll need to determine the next ID before performing each insert which would make all of your `INSERT` queries unnecessarily complex and the code more difficult to maintain.  Not to mention introducing a significant point of failure if multiple threads try to insert and the operation to find the next ID and insert a record isn't fully atomic.

Why do you even need this?  There's no reason for a database-generated primary key integer to be contiguous like that.  Its purpose is to be unique, and as long as it serves that purpose it's working.  There's no need to "fill in the holes" left by previously deleted records.

You *could* add a different column to the database and perform the logic for finding the next contiguous number when inserting records on that column.  But you'd still run into the same aforementioned problems of race conditions and unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Change your filename to something more meaningful than the id.

I think something like `files/uploads/20130515_170349.wv` (for the first row) makes a lot of sense (assuming you don't have more than one file per second.

This also has the advantage that ordering the file names alphabetically is chronological order, making it easier to see the newer and older files.

Answer (score 0):

You can just give it the I'd field and value

Insert into table (I'd, etc, etc) values (5, etc, etc);

However I don't think you can do it dynamically. If I'd is auto increment then it'll keep on oncrementinf whether or not previous tuples have been deleted etc.